# whats wrong with this Sparql query

Tags: sparql

I have a Parent Class "Causes" which has SubClasses "Agging","BadLifeStyle" Each Class Causes has a datatype property "name" with individuals (Class=>Individuals) Causes => Cause_1,Agging => Agging_1,BadLifeStyle => BadLifeStyle_1
I want to get results like this

```
Ind                SubCLassOF               type
Agging_1           Causes                   Agging
BadLifeStyle_1     Causes                   BadLifeStyle
Cause_1                                     Causes
```

I wrote this query

```
SELECT *
    WHERE {

          ?cause rdf:type ?typename.
          ?cause rdfs:subClassOf ?subClass.
          OPTIONAL{?cause NS:name ?name.}
           FILTER(REGEX(STR(?typename),"Causes","i")
          || REGEX(STR(?subClass),"Causes","i"))
    }
```

It didnt give me Cause_1 individual

Comment: Duplicate question on answers.semanticweb.com: http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/12042/help-me-in-this-sparql-query

Answer (score 2):

Syntactically your query looks fine, not sure what's the problem...

Usually I prefer to perform a [UNION](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#alternatives) for such kind of operations, in our case something like:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
  {
    ?cause rdf:type ?typename .
    FILTER(REGEX(STR(?typename), "Causes", "i"))  
  } UNION {
    ?cause rdfs:subClassOf ?subClass .
    FILTER(REGEX(STR(?subClass), "Causes", "i"))
  }
  OPTIONAL{?cause NS:name ?name.}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using virtuoso server for RDF and sparql.
In virtuoso, we have to add one space or enter before OPTIONAL then OPTIONAL will work in virtuoso. 
So Add one space or enter befor OPTIONAL then u will able to get results.
Hope this will work for this Query.